# Trying to input user information to 2 tables at once sql

Tags: android-studio, transactions, azure-sql-database

I am trying to add data to 2 tables at the same time via user input, however all its doing is inserting into the first table and not the 2nd.The code is for an azure sql  database

```
String query = "BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO cc_customer (customer_id,customer_first_name,customer_surname,customer_tel_number,customer_cell_number,customer_status,employee_number) 
VALUES ('"+id.toString()+"','"+ name.toString()+"','"+ Lname.toString()+"','"+ Telnum.toString()+"','"+Cellnum.toString()+"','"+Status.toString()+"','"+Empnum.toString()+"');
"+" 
INSERT INTO cc_customer_address (customer_address_id,customer_building_number,customer_street,customer_suburb,customer_city,customer_zip_code) 
VALUES ('"+Cusnum.toString()+"','"+ Cusbuild.toString()+"','"+ Cusstr.toString()+"','"+ Cussub.toString()+"','"+Cuscity.toString()+"','"+Cuszip.toString()+"')COMMIT;";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked!!!!

```
String query = "BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERT INTO cc_customer(customer_id,customer_first_name,customer_surname,customer_tel_number,customer_cell_number,customer_status,employee_number) VALUES ('"+id.toString()+"','"+name.toString()+"','"+Lname.toString()+"','"+Telnum.toString()+"','"+Cellnum.toString()+"','"+Status.toString()+"','"+Empnum.toString()+"')"+"INSERT INTO cc_customer_address(customer_number,customer_building_number,customer_street,customer_suburb,customer_city,customer_zip_code) VALUES ('"+Cusnum.toString()+"','"+Cusbuild.toString()+"','"+Cusstr.toString()+"','"+Cussub.toString()+"','"+Cuscity.toString()+"','"+Cuszip.toString()+"') COMMIT";
```